# Redirect url with a . at the end after the file extension?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have a website thats been featured in the papers, theyve posted my address as so...

www.mysite.com/about.php.

If you visit the above it 404's as the `dot` on the end of the php...

Is there a way in htaccess I can redirect this to the correct page?

**Current htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\. $1.php

RewriteRule ^people/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?county=$1&name=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^people-in-(.*) /people.php?county=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.+$ $1 [L,QSA,R=301]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `RewriteRule` will do the trick :

```
RewriteRule (.*\.php)\.$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\. $1.php
```

Comment: No luck @Pitchinnate, Ive added my full htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\.$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: No luck @Akam, still 404

Comment: Could any of my other rules be conflicting @akam? I dont have a clue how htaccess works sorry

Comment: re-organize your rules and remove duplicate lines, try to put only my rule and test then add one by one to see where is the conflict because I don't know which one is

Comment: It seems my wordpress redirect is breaking this :\... 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>